# How to prepopulate a Green DAO sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, populate, greendao

I am about to use the Green DAO ORM tool. I am going to have to insert about six hundreds rows of data into my database. I am wondering there is a way to prepopulate the database using some form of sqlite database management tool or a script. I dont want to manually add each of these entities and so on. in android code. It would be too tedious and time consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your data in a CSV/JSON file. Then on the onCreate method of your DBHelper, read the file and insert them into your database.